# JS subset of array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array of arrays as follows:

```
[ [ A0 , B0 , C0 , D0 , E0 ],
  [ A1 , B1 , C1 , D1 , E1 ],
  [ A2 , B2 , C2 , D2 , E2 ]  ] // array of 3x5
```

and I want to get a new array of subset arrays like so:

```
[ [ A0 , B0 , C0           ],
  [      B1 , C1 , D1      ],
  [           C2 , D2 , E2 ]  ]  //array of 3x3
```

This means that the sliceLength = 3, but how can one do this?  Is it better to use splice (as in duplicate the original, then remove the unwanted parts), slice, and/or push?

This is what I have thus far, but the syntax looks off:

```
var newMega = [];
var sliceLength = 3;
for (var i=0; i<originalMatrix.length; i++) {
  var inner = originalMatrix.slice(i, sliceLength);  //  Here is the issue
  newMega.push(inner); 
}
```

It appears that the syntax would call slice on the entire originalMatrix, without knowing which index of the nested arrays it should be slicing.  Should it be `originalMatrix[i].slice(i, sliceLength)`?

Comment: I don't think `.slice` is the correct method to use here. It looks like you want to end up with 3 arrays of length 5, but without values at some positions. `.slice` will always return an array of length three in your case. It looks like you have to `delete` the elements that you don't want. This will preserve the length (5) of each inner array.

Comment: Do you want to end up with arrays if length 3 or length 5? *edit:* Ok :) Your example looks a bit like you wanted a sparse matrix.

Comment: @FelixKling sorry for this misconception, 3x3

Comment: @FelixKling Well, you just cost me another 10 minutes looking into what a sparse array is!   Thanks, learning a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try slicing the inner array (`originalMatrix[i]`). Also, you probably want to call [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) rather than [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var newMega = [];
var spliceLength = 3;
for (var i=0; i<originalMatrix.length; i++) {
  var inner = originalMatrix[i].splice(i, spliceLength);
  newMega.push(inner); 
}
```

Here's a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EkWyU/).

Comment: This would result in each of the inner arrays have a length of three. Based on the OP's example I don't think that's what they want, but I could be just misinterpreting the example.

Comment: @FelixKling That's exactly the way I read the question. Each sub-array has length 3.

Comment: I read it that each arrays should still have length 5, but has "holes" at some positions. Anyways, the OP clarified and your interpretation is correct.